# Why does patsubst stop working when using secondary expansion of $$*?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Here is an example from the [GNU Make manual section on Secondary Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Secondary-Expansion) (slightly simplified):

```
foo_SRCS := bar.c baz.c

.SECONDEXPANSION:
# $$@ expands to the target ("foo" in this case)
foo: $$(patsubst %.c,%.o,$$($$@_SRCS))
```

This works great; it builds `bar.o` and `baz.o`:

```
cc    -c -o bar.o bar.c
cc    -c -o baz.o baz.c
```

But if I tweak this example only slightly, the `patsubst` stops working:

```
all: foo.a

foo_SRCS := bar.c baz.c

.SECONDEXPANSION:
# $$* expands to the stem of the match ("foo" in this case).
%.a: $$(patsubst %.c,%.o,$$($$*_SRCS))
        ar rcs $@ $^
```

It is no longer building `bar.o` and `baz.o`, and instead is using the `*.c` files directly as prerequisites!

```
ar rcs foo.a bar.c baz.c
```

Please note that the `$$($$*_SRCS)` part is clearly working, as evidenced by the fact that it found `foo_SRCS` and used that as the prerequisites.  But for some reason the `patsubst` part has become a no-op!  Instead of replacing `%.c` with `%.o`, it is just using `foo_SRCS` directly.

What is going on here?  How can I get my example to work?

EDIT: I had a theory that the `%` characters inside the `patsubst` were getting evaluated early, using the stem match (foo), so that the patsubst itself was looking something like this:

```
$(patsubst foo.c,foo.o,bar.c baz.c)
```

To test this theory, I added a file called `foo.c` to `foo_SRCS`:

```
all: foo.a

foo_SRCS := foo.c bar.c baz.c

.SECONDEXPANSION:
# $$* expands to the stem of the match ("foo" in this case).
%.a: $$(patsubst %.c,%.o,$$($$*_SRCS))
        ar rcs $@ $^
```

That resulted in something even weirder:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `foo.a', needed by `all'.  Stop.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The percent characters are being read by make as matches to the wildcard in the stem and are being replaced with the stem match. If you check the `make -p` output for your example you'll see that the parsed target line looks like this:

```
%.a: $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$($*_SRCS))
```

Which, as far as make is concerned, is just a really odd set of patterned targets (or something like that).

If you escape the percent characters from make parsing in a similar way to how you escape the `$` from make evaluation you can get what you want to work:

```
pc := %
$$(patsubst $$(pc).c,$$(pc).o,$$($$*_SRCS))
```

For added information [substitution references](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Substitution-Refs) (i.e. `$(foo_SRCS:.c=.o)`) can be used for transformations like this in place of the longer call to patsubst. In this case however, while it works in this scenario with a similar escaping of `:` (via `c := :`) it doesn't seem to function as the sole prerequisite of the target (with make giving a `Makefile:23: *** commands commence before first target.  Stop.` error that I don't quite understand) at least with GNU Make 3.81.

Comment: Make's parser is not very clever. When make sees your attempt it unescapes the `$$` into `$` and ends up with the line indicated above. It then sees that as a normal pattern rule. Pattern rules take the target pattern, match the target filename against it to extract a stem and then replace that stem in the prerequisite list in place of every `%`. This breaks the patsubst since it no longer contains any `%` characters when the secondary expansion expands it. Escaping `%` characters lets make see them only once secondary expansion is happening and not when the pattern rule is being stem matched.

Comment: All that makes sense to me. The part I don't understand then is why the original example (from the Make manual) works at all.  Why wouldn't it fail in the same way?

Comment: Good point. My analysis of the problem might be incorrect in some measure. Additionally the manual section you linked explicitly states that "The variables $$? and $$* are not available and expand to the empty string." so this shouldn't work at all so I wonder what is going on exactly.

Comment: Oh wait, I have a new theory. Maybe it is replacing the `%` characters in the patsubst, so that it ends up looking like: `$(patsubst foo.c,foo.o,bar.c baz.c)`! I have to test this theory now.

Comment: It only replaces the *first* `%` of the patsubst, so you get `$(patsubst foo.c,%.o,...)`. I've given an answer where I tried to write it out in detail.

Answer (score 4):

You're mixing three features that don't go well together: [secondary expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Secondary-Expansion.html#Secondary-Expansion), [pattern rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Rules.html#Pattern-Rules), and [patsubst](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html#index-patsubst-1). I'll try to explain in detail what make is doing when evaluating your code (AFAIUI).

Let's start with your first Makefile:

```
foo_SRCS := bar.c baz.c

.SECONDEXPANSION:
%.a: $$(patsubst %.c,%.o,$$($$*_SRCS))
        ar rcs $@ $^
```

**Read phase.** All dollar signs are escaped, so no evaluation happens here. Make enters the following rule in its database:

```
%.a: $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$($*_SRCS))
```

**Pattern substitution.** As far as make is concerned, this is just another pattern rule, with target `%.a` and two prerequisites separated by whitespace: `$(patsubst` and `%.c,%.o,$($*_SRCS))`.

`foo.a` matches the target pattern, and so the *first* `%` in each prerequisite will be replaced by `foo`. The rule becomes:

```
foo.a: $(patsubst foo.c,%.o,$($*_SRCS))
```

**Target update phase.** As you requested secondary expansion, the pattern is evaluated again in the target update phase:

```
    foo.a: $(patsubst foo.c,%.o,$($*_SRCS))
==> foo.a: $(patsubst foo.c,%.o,bar.c baz.c)
==> foo.a: bar.c baz.c
```

And so make ends up executing the command

```
ar rcs foo.a bar.c baz.c
```

**And what about foo.c?** If you add foo.c to foo_SRCS, the secondary expansion looks like this:

```
    foo.a: $(patsubst foo.c,%.o,$($*_SRCS))
==> foo.a: $(patsubst foo.c,%.o,foo.c bar.c baz.c)
==> foo.a: %.o bar.c baz.c
```

And the rule fails because make doesn't know how to build `%.o`.

**Work-around.** You can escape the `%` characters with a backslash:

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
%.a: $(patsubst \%.c,\%.o,$$($$*_SRCS))
        ar rcs $@ $^
```